# Custom Death Message not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, technical-issues

I'm making a custom map for Minecraft. In it, all players die by going into water. This is the command I have:

```
/execute at @a[distance=..100] if block ~ ~ ~ water run tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"white","extra":[{"selector":"@p"},{"text":" died by touching the water"}]}
```

But when I touch the water the command just spams the chat, and if I make it impulse the command won't run if I touch the water.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/tag

Answer (score 0):

You could tag the player that touched the water, which clarifies who touched the water and indicates they have already had the text displayed. Then the repeating command block should point at a conditional chain command block with a tellraw that checks for that tag.  The next trick will be removing the tag after they're not in the water anymore, which could be roughly the same command, except checking if they have the tag and they're in air. You can add it as its own repeating command or an unconditional chain command.

Here's the code I came up with. I checked it with 1 player, but I don't have another player handy to check for more. Notice the selector in the tellraw includes an argument checking for the tag.

```
execute at @a as @a[distance=..100,tag=!water] anchored feet if block ~ ~ ~ water run tag @s add water

tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"white","extra":[{"selector":"@p[tag=water]"},{"text":" died by touching the water"}]}

execute at @a as @a[distance=..100,tag=water] anchored feet if block ~ ~ ~ air run tag @s remove water
```

UPDATE: Revised code to include "anchored" to prevent pointing at the wrong place... but still haven't been able to test with multiple players.

Comment: It didn't really work, the player who got execute was the one that was the nearest to the command block.  Do you get any other solutions?

Comment: Did the tag get assigned correctly? That seems like the likeliest place for that setup to come apart. The "@s" doesn't seem to work the way I expect it to. Try putting in another @a[distance..100,tag=!water] instead. Maybe @a[tag=water] in place of the @p[tag=water] too.

Comment: Never mind the "@a" stuff. It won't work. The trouble we're having is that the check for the block is still coming from the command block. Even if we're telling it to look where the player is, we're not getting the player to run the command, which would let the @s work. I'm looking for another way now.

Comment: Fun little quirk... you have to use the "anchored" parameter to specify eyes or feet or the command will revert to a previous caller.... I still don't have multiple players to test with, but I will revise the code above. Let me know if it's working any better.